# BigQuery table partitioning by month

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't find any documentation relating to this. Is time_partitioning_type=DAY the only way to partition a table in BigQuery? Can this parameter take any other values besides a date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that even if you partition on day granularity, you can still write your queries to operate at the level of months using an appropriate filter on `_PARTITIONTIME`. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM MyDatePartitionedTable
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM _PARTITIONTIME), MONTH) = '2017-01-01';
```

This selects all rows from January of this year.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. BigQuery **currently** only supports date-partitioned tables.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

> BigQuery offers date-partitioned tables, which means that the table is divided into a separate partition for each date

Comment: Update 2022 - the linked-to documentation now documents how to do this: "For TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, the partitions can have either hourly, daily, monthly, or yearly granularity. For DATE columns, the partitions can have daily, monthly, or yearly granularity."

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this would work:

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `My_Partition_Table`
 PARTITION BY event_month
 OPTIONS (
    description="this is a table partitioned by month"
  ) AS
  SELECT
   DATE_TRUNC(DATE(some_event_timestamp), month) as event_month,
   *
  FROM `TableThatNeedsPartitioning`
```

Comment: The only caveat is that you need to use event_month in your queries, so if you're looking for something on 2019-01-15 you would need to specify 
`and event_month='2019-01-01'`

Answer (score 1):

For those that run into the error "Too many partitions produced by query, allowed 4000, query produces at least X partitions", due to the [4000 partitions BigQuery limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49539016) as of 2023.02, you can do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `My_Partition_Table`
  PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC(date_column, MONTH)
  OPTIONS (
    description="This is a table partitioned by month"
  ) AS
-- Your query
```

Basically, take @david-salmela 's answer, but move the `DATE_TRUNC` part to the `PARTITION BY` section.

It seems to work exactly like `PARTITION BY date_column` in terms of querying the table (e.g. `WHERE date_column = "2023-02-20"`), but my understanding is that you always retrieve data for a whole month in terms of cost.